# Google Sheet Link Drop Down / Dependend Lists

Tags: google-sheets

how can I make a drop down list in google sheet dependent on other data ?

I added a picture and shared the google spreadsheet to make things clear :-)

[image]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t3PeVcAFnh4SU9CrxrX4_jjFq-EtkQvJmdTdXTVCeSE/edit?usp=sharing

*Drop Down List A --> Show the list based on what is written in A1*

or

*Get Drop Down List A by value in A1*

After that a picture should show up in the next column based on the value of the drop down list.

Hope you can help?

Answer (score 0):

place this in M3:

```
=TRANSPOSE(IF(B3=$F$3, $G$3:$G$5, IF(B3=$F$4, $I$3:$I$5, IF(B3=$F$5, $K$3:$K$4, )))
```

in C3 create data validation from M3:3 range

[image]

use in D3:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(C3:C, {G3:H;I3:J;K3:L}, 2, 0)))
```

[image]